# Understanding APB services and repositories

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am learning the APB and I am analyzing and extending the code from the Introduction Part 2 tutorial (ASP.NET Core, EF). https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Introduction-With-AspNet-Core-And-Entity-Framework-Core-Part-2/index.html

First I introduced a new entity - Team. Team is a group of people. I added the foreign key to the Person entity.

```cs
[Table("AppPersons")]
public class Person : AuditedEntity<Guid>
{
    public const int MaxNameLength = 32;

    [Required]
    [StringLength(MaxNameLength)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TeamId))]
    public Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to create an ApplicationService that will return the list of people for a specific team with the number of assigned tasks. I don't know how should I combine the Repository and Mapping infrastructure to achieve this.

```cs
public class FooAppService : ApplicationService, IFooAppService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Task, Guid> _taskRepository;

    public FooAppService(IRepository<Task, Guid> taskRepository)
    {
        _taskRepository = taskRepository;
    }

    public ListResultDto<PersonWithNumberOfTasksAssignedDto> FooMethod(Guid teamId)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

I also don't know what is the best way to design the DTO object. Do I need a new DTO object for this service method or should I use a tuple? I do have a `PersonDto` object that is used to add/edit Person. Should I just wrap it with a count property?

```cs
public class PersonWithNumberOfTasksAssignedDto : EntityDto<Guid>
{
    public PersonDto Person { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfAssignedTasks { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can take reference from Abp free startup template.

```
public async Task<PersonDto> Create(PersonCreateInput input)
{
    var person = ObjectMapper.Map<Person>(input);

    await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

    return MapToEntityDto(person);
}
```

For example, `UserAppService.Create()` https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/164a5c9e28cb29383551d0f3310986ab43d0ceed/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Application/Users/UserAppService.cs#L55-L76

To retrieve list of items, you can leverage on the `AsyncCrudAppService` base class which provides sorting and pagination out of the box (via `AsyncCrudAppService.GetAll()`.
See https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/14c4fe5a5408a66e913a434688b951815247827d/src/Abp/Application/Services/AsyncCrudAppService.cs#L112-L129

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I am asking about retrieving and mapping  the "list of people for a specific team with the number of assigned tasks".